# What happens when you don’t hang thieves?

Tags: a-dark-room

In *A Dark Room*, when the villagers catch a thief, the player is given the option to hang them or spare them. I always hang them, because the theft is so crippling and can go on for so long.

Has anybody ever tried sparing them? What happens? Does the thieving stop anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After digging through the code, I found the scene in global.js. In both cases, whether you hang the thief or spare him, the stealing stops. What differs is what you get in addition to that: If you spare the thief, you get a perk 'stealthy', which lowers the chance you encounter a fight in the wilds. If you hang him, you get everything the thieves stole back.